# What is the purpose of the default site collections?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

In our SharePoint admin portal, we have the following site collections. We created none of these.

- [tenant].sharepoint.com
- [tenant].sharepoint.com/portals/community
- [tenant].sharepoint.com/portals/hub
- [tenant].sharepoint.com/search
- [tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/CompliancePolicyCenter
- [tenant]-my.sharepoint.com
- [tenant]-public.sharepoint.com

Questions:

- What is the purpose of each?
- Can we delete each of them?

Answer (score 7):

This is my best guess for each Site Collection, though I have been able to find limited official documentation.

#### domain.sharepoint.com

- This is the top level (aka root) SharePoint Site Collection.
- Okay to delete, if you want all Site Collections to be inaccessible.
- It is also possible to recreate this (see references) though this can take upwards of 15-minutes.
- Both `domain-my.sharepoint.com` and `domain.sharepoint.com/search` remain accessible after deleting the root.

#### domain.sharepoint.com/portals/community

- Lists all community sites available on your company intranet.
- Okay to delete and possible to recreate (see references.)

#### domain.sharepoint.com/portals/hub

- Goes to the Office 365 Video page.
- Okay to delete and possible to recreate (see references.)

#### domain.sharepoint.com/search

- Goes to the search page.
- Cannot delete (delete is disabled.)

#### domain.sharepoint.com/sites/CompliancePolicyCenter

- Goes to the Compliance Policy Center for SharePoint.
- Okay to delete.

#### domain-my.sharepoint.com

- The OneDrive for Business page of the currently logged in user.
- Cannot delete (delete is disabled.)

#### domain-public.sharepoint.com

- This is our public facing website.
- Okay to delete, if we are not using it as our LIVE website.

### Annotated References

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/403878 Portals (community and hub) [are] created automatically when setting up your tenant along with tenant.sharepoint.com/search and tenant-my.sharepoint.com, these site collections are pre-defined.

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/420137 Hub and Community portal recreation is possible as administrators, though to recover data we need to contact Microsoft support.

1. Recreate /portal/hub by going to /_layouts/15/videoredirect.aspx
2. Recreate /portal/community by creating a video channel named Community.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/2559901 Restore or recreate the root site collection after you have deleted it.

### Screen Shots

**After deleting everything that is possible to delete.**
[image: After deleting everything that is possible to delete]

**Compliance Policy Center for SharePoint** that we deleted.
[image: Compliance Policy Center for SharePoint]

**Community Portal** that we deleted.
[image: Community Portal]

**Hub Portal** that we deleted and recreated. 
[image: Hub Portal]

Comment: domain.sharepoint.com is a site collection in SharePoint Online.